# Why has my answer to my own question been deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/when-is-the-setter-allowed-to-leave-his-position) question some time ago. An answer was posted but it didn't directly refer to my question but to some flaw it allegedly contained.
After some time of researching, I learned that there is indeed no such rule and wrote that as an answer to my own question. Admittedly, it was not the best answer because I didn't show any proof or something but anyway.
It got downvoted once and later deleted.

Could anyone tell me what was so bad about the answer? I also addressed the creator of the other answer but he hasn't responded yet...
And do you think that other answer is on point and addresses my very question? IMHO, it isn't. The most helpful part was a comment beneath it saying

> There are no such rules; see 7.5.1 as I've quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer has two parts:

> Alright, I know for a fact now that it's really against the rules as @PhillipKendall correctly stated.

This simply acknowledges someone else's answer as being correct without adding new information. An upvote would be preferred.

> The thing is that on international level, the setters occasionally **do** leave their position early but that's hard to judge from the view of the 2<sup>nd</sup> referee. That's the source of my confusion.

This offers more background and could be edited into the question, but it too is not an answer.

I deleted the answer because neither part seemed to be an actual answer to the question.

Comment: OK, after rereading my question and answer in depth, it seems bad to me too. ^^ FYI, I did upvote the other answer. Someone downvoted (I'm not assuming it was you) but I think some commentary on that would be appropriate, wouldn't it? I also asked the creator of the other answer but he hasn't responded yet... have I been too rude?

Comment: @cad If you notice, I did edit your [comment about being kind](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/when-is-the-setter-allowed-to-leave-his-position#comment19305_12588). Nonetheless, I don't think it's too much to ask for a response, but don't hold out for one. If he doesn't respond, he doesn't respond. Also, some commentary is always appropriate, but that is more ideal than typical.